# Combinatorics: How many celebrations will be on the same night?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I was tutoring someone today and they gave me an interesting homework problem I was unable to solve. I was wondering if any of you could help me.

"Four different Spanish restaurants are planning a customer appreciation night in November 2014, a month with 30 days. What is the probability that 2 or more of these celebrations will be on same night?"

My thoughts was to compute the complement event: having 1 or 0 celebrations in the same night. I reasoned that there was 1 way to have 0 celebrations and 4 ways to have 1 celebration for a total of 5 outcomes favorable. And the total number of outcomes was $2^4$. So the probability would be $1 - \frac{5}{2^4}$ but apparently the answer is 0.1880 or $\frac{47}{250}$. Can someone explain this? Perhaps there isn't enough information to solve this?

Comment: How would you have fewer outcomes than days?

Comment: First find the probability they all choose *different* nights. Note that we will have to make the unreasonable assumption that all choices are equally likely, and that they are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We make the assumption that the sample space (all ways restaurants choose their customer appreciation days) is equiprobable.

Approach this via multiplication principle and try to count the opposite event (all celebration days are on *different* nights).

How many ways can the first restaurant choose its celebration day?  (30 ways)

How many ways can the second restaurant choose its celebration day and it not be the same as the first restaurant's choice? (29 ways)

How many ways can the third restaurant choose its celebration day and it not be the same as either of the first two? (28 ways)

Similarly, the fourth restaurant will have 27 choices.

How many ways can the four restaurants choose their days if we don't care about duplicated days?  ($30^4$)

The probability that all celebrations lie on different days is then $\frac{30\cdot 29\cdot 28\cdot 27}{30^4}=\frac{203}{250}$, so the probability that at least one day is chosen by at least two of the restaurants is then $\frac{47}{250}$

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! I wasn't understanding how the number of days was needed for the problem. This problem was bugging me, thank you so much!